# With JavaScript, how can I replace long sequences of text with ellipsis?

Tags: javascript, string

I have some text like:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <strong class="ner" style="background-color: #2fbbab">nine months <small>datetime</small></strong>
    Urna condimentum mattis <strong class="ner" style="background-color: #2fbbab">December 20th <small>datetime</small></strong>
    Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut
    <strong class="ner" style="background-color: #2fbbab">December 1st<small>datetime</small></strong>
    Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut
```

I want to add ellipsis in the beginning, at the end and in between `<strong>` tags if there are more than 5 words.

I managed to do the beginning and end with:

```
      let firstHighlightIndex = text.indexOf("<strong");
      let lastHighlightIndex =
        text.lastIndexOf("</strong>") + "</strong>".length;
      let preText = text.substr(0, firstHighlightIndex).split(" ");
      let postText = text.substr(lastHighlightIndex).split(" ");
      text = text.slice(firstHighlightIndex, lastHighlightIndex);

      if (preText.length > 5) {
        preText = ["..."].concat(preText.slice(preText.length - 4));
      }

      if (postText.length > 5) {
        postText = postText.slice(0, 4).concat("...");
      }

      text = preText.join(" ") + text + postText.join(" ");
```

However, how can I do all of the middle portions? My goal is to have the text resemble:

```
    ... et dolore magna aliqua.
    <strong class="ner" style="background-color: #2fbbab">nine months <small>datetime</small></strong>
    Urna condimentum mattis <strong class="ner" style="background-color: #2fbbab">December 20th <small>datetime</small></strong>
    Euismod lacinia at ... vulputate odio ut
    <strong class="ner" style="background-color: #2fbbab">December 1st<small>datetime</small></strong>
    Euismod lacinia at ...
```

Thank you

Comment: It would be nice if you give some example of how it is being displayed now and how you want it to be, the desired output. It would let your question a little more clear

Comment: Why don't you use css? text-overflow: ellipsis;

Comment: @David because he wants ellipsis in the beginning, middle and end, when there's 5 words or more, its very specific, CSS solution probably won't be useful here

Comment: @CalvinNunes ok, i see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, how can I do all of the middle portions?

You could use a regular expression to match and replace the middle portions, like the demo code below.

```js
function f(text){
  return text.replace(
    /<\/strong>(([^<]|<(?!strong))+)<strong/gi, 
    function(fullmatch, middle){
      middle = middle.split(' ');
      if(middle.length > 5){
        return '<\/strong>' + 
        middle.slice(0,3).join(' ') +
        ' ... ' +
        middle.slice(-3).join(' ') +
        '<strong';
      }else{
        return fullmatch;
      }
    }
  );
}

let text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ' +
  'consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do ' +
  'eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et ' +
  'dolore magna aliqua.\n<strong class="ner" ' +
  'style="background-color: #2fbbab">nine ' +
  'months <small>datetime</small></strong>\n' +
  'Urna condimentum mattis \n<strong class="ner" ' +
  'style="background-color: #2fbbab">December ' +
  '20th <small>datetime</small></strong>\n' +
  'Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate ' +
  'odio ut\n<strong class="ner" style="background-color: ' +
  '#2fbbab">December 1st<small>datetime</small></strong>\n' +
  'Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut';
  
console.log(f(text))
```